# Google Maps: navigating between Marker and Indoor Marker

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-indoor-maps

Is it possible to create a route between a Google Maps Marker and a POI of a Indoor Map using the Google Maps API? For "classic" Markers you can use the Directions API, but it seems to be limited to "classic" Markers only.

In the example below I've created a route between an address and a POI inside the Madison Square Garden with Google Maps, but how to realize it through the API?

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFFOf.png

Source: https://www.google.com/maps/dir/40.7510242,-73.9931116/40.751578,-73.9939041/@40.7512401,-73.9939461,19.55z/data=!4m2!4m1!3e2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use the [turn-by-turn navigation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intents#launch_turn-by-turn_navigation) under Google Maps API. It gives turn-by-turn directions to the address or coordinate specified. Directions are always given from the users current location.

```
google.navigation:q=a+street+address

google.navigation:q=latitude,longitude
```

This is the parameters that you can use.

- `q`: Sets the end point for navigation searches. This can be a latitude,longitude or a query formatted address. If it is a query string that returns more than one result, the first result will be selected.
- `mode` sets the method of transportation. Mode is optional, defaults to driving, and can be set to one of:
- `d` for driving
- `w` for walking
- `b` for bicycling
- `avoid` sets features the route should try to avoid. Avoid is optional and can be set to one or more of:
- `t` for tolls
- `h` for highways
- `f` for ferries

The below intent will give you an example of turn-by-turn navigation.

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=Taronga+Zoo,+Sydney+Australia");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

I hope it can help you in your problem.

Comment: Is this possible without launching the Google Maps App? I want to do this using only the Maps API for Android and keep users inside my app.